# I need to make a program that will find the average of 15 test grades

Tags: vb.net, exception, comments, average

First of all the program, must find the average of the 15 numbers. then must give a grade accordingly For example if the grade where a 88 the program would print the grade B. Also the program must use some sort of User-Defined example.

Now for my question. In the program below i got it to calculate the average of 15 numbers however, i cant find a way for the exception to detect if the user has inputted something other than a number. I tried to make it Try for the gradetotal as decimal but that seems to be unacceptable. So is there an alternative way or am i overlooking something?

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10, num11, num12, num13, num14, num15, gradetotal As Decimal
        Console.WriteLine("The Average Of 10 numbers")
        Console.Write("Input Test Grade 1: ")
        num1 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Input Test Grade 2: ")
        num2 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Input Test Grade 3: ")
        num3 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Input Test Grade 4: ")
        num4 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Input Test Grade 5: ")
        num5 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Input Test Grade 6: ")
        num6 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Input Test Grade 7: ")
        num7 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Input Test Grade 8: ")
        num8 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Input Test Grade 9: ")
        num9 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Input Test Grade 10: ")
        num10 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Input Test Grade 11: ")
        num11 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Input Test Grade 12: ")
        num12 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Input Test Grade 13: ")
        num13 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Input Test Grade 14: ")
        num14 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Input Test Grade 15: ")
        num15 = Console.ReadLine()

        gradetotal = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6 + num7 + num8 + num9 + num10 + num11 + num12 + num13 + num14 + num15

        Try
            If gradetotal = Decimal Then

            Else
                Throw New Exception()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Your Grade Average Is:" & (gradetotal) / 15)

        End Try
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub
End Module
```

Finally can anyone explain to me how to make this program have a comment block with all the key information and a single and multi line comments?

Comment: Go to your project settings and change Option Strict Off to On and you will see where is the problem. A string is not a decimal, then search how to convert a string to a decimal value without raising an exception

Comment: I cant see to find this Option strict. However, the problem is i am trying to check if the user inputted any thing other than a number, but i cant just make it gradetotal = decimal. so how would i alter the exception part to make it due that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if your user has written a number without raising an exception you should use the Decimal.TryParse method that returns false if the typed value is not a decimal number. Of course decimal numbers are tricky because you should consider also the character used in your culture to indicate the decimal separator.

Said that, you also need to change that big input sequence using a loop and storing the inputs received in some sort of collection. In the example below I use a List(Of Decimal) and apply the IEnumerable extension to get the sum and the average of your inputs.

```
Sub Main
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim grades = New List(Of Decimal)()
    While count < 15
        Console.WriteLine("Enter " & count + 1 & " grade")
        Dim input = Console.ReadLine()
        Dim temp As Decimal
        ' InvariantCulture uses the point as decimal separator,
        ' if your culture uses something different use CurrentCulture instead
        If Decimal.TryParse(input, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,
                                   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, temp) Then
            grades.Add(temp)
            count += 1
        End If 
    End While

    Console.WriteLine("Total:" & grades.Sum())
    Console.WriteLine("Average:" & grades.Average())
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay I can try and work with that. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Also i have Up-voted your answer but it only becomes public once i gain 15 rep points.